# Selenium Python - Scription Return empty string and unable to compare by assertequal

Tags: python, selenium

I created a selenium script to check the number of cart is shown zero (0)> However, it's returned empty although this field is zero.

**Scripts:**

```
shopping_cart_qty = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'topnav-cart-qty')]").text
        self.assertEqual('0', shopping_cart_qty, "The shopping car is not empty")
```

**Return:**

```
The shopping car is not empty
 != 0

Expected :0
Actual   :
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
shopping_cart_qty = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'topnav-cart-qty')]").get_attribute("value")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
shopping_cart_qty = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'topnav-cart-qty')]").get_attribute("textContent")

or 

shopping_cart_qty = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'topnav-cart-qty')]")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()",shopping_cart_qty )

print(shopping_cart_qty.text)
```

if element is not visible then text will return empty as it considers the visibility also, you can use textContent to retrieve the text irrespective of the visibility .

But the best way is to scrollintoview first and then get text